# How to Call via a PC and Modem?

Tags: windows

How can i call to someone using my PC that connected to a Router ? ( Router: TP-LINK TD-W8961ND ) (Windows: 7) 
It was possible with Dial-Up connection, but is there any way to do this like using Tele-Phone ?

Comment: do you mean to call someone that is connected to the same router or just a router on the Internet?

Comment: @angs: I want to call via my Phone line that connected to my router from my PC to any Phone Lines.

Comment: Search on the internet for "computer phone answering machine" and you find some software that can also do what you ask.

Comment: @Aristos: How can i find out that my router supports that and which programs i need ?

Comment: @AmirrezA_Nasiri I am not sure, maybe with try and fail. I have done that some years ago with ISDN modem and it work,

Comment: do i have to have got a Voice Modem ? is there any easier ways ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Jay M - it sounds like you have a DSL modem.  DSL doesn't do "direct" analog voice like older 56k analog does.

Undoubtedly your ISP has given you a number of filters, and you probably discovered you had to put one on any phone jack that you are NOT using for your DSL.  This is necessary so you don't hear the DSL signal while on a voice call.

So you can still run a phone cord from your PC's landline modem to any phone jack, IF you put a filter on it.  You should then be able to make normal analog calls using the same tools.  You'll even be able to do this at the same time your Internet is up.  (You *might* even be able to dial in to your ISP at the same time your DSL is active - not terribly useful - if your ISP offers backup dialup service - but the filter may interfere with near 56k speeds.  I've never tried it.)

There are also DSL filters that have two jacks, one for audio and one for the DSL.  You can put one of these where you are connecting your DSL to the wall now to continue to use voice with that same line.  See below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a model number on your router? Your router sounds like a DSL router. If this is the case, it's not meant to handle voice calls, only data.

You may want to look into searching skype, google voice, or SIP to make PC-to-phone calls.

Comment: my router modem is TP-LINK TD-W8961ND . i think it have no voice case !